# Generic Compare function

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a generic compare function to see if two instances of a class which may hold member variables that are a List<>.

```cs
bool IsEqual<T>(T a, T b)
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach(var property in props)
    {
        var aVal = property.GetValue(a);
        var bVal = property.GetValue(b);
        if (aVal as System.Collections.IEnumerable != null)
        {
        // Convert into lists, do something with SequenceEqual and possibly recursive call to IsEqual
        }

        if (!Equals(aVal,bVal)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm not sure how to convert a given member variable to a proper list, so I can do a SequenceEqual on it to compare the lists.

The classes that I will use in IsEqual() are not native to my program but comes from a DLL.

Comment: `aVal as List<T>` or `bVal as List<T>`? Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Not entirely, as aVal/bVal won't be of the type T supplied in the initial call to IsEqual

Comment: Why not just make a separate method for Lists `AreListsEqual<T>(List<T> a, List<T> b)`?  Additionally adding an `IEquatable` constraint on `T` would allow you to just do `a.Equals(b)` and then you leave it up to the class to define how to determine if they are equal.  Otherwise you have to mess with reflection that is slow.

Comment: Well, when I supply an object of type T, I can't know (since the function is supposed to be generic) which member variables are lists, and what type they are a list *of*. I can't add IEquatable to a class that is not mine (in my program)...
But if I could get the type of the values' list, and then make var aValList = aVal as List<somehow get the right type>, I'd be happy

Comment: Thanks @kara that was exactly what I needed. I've been searching and searching, but that one didn't come up...

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code work for you?

```
public static bool DeepEquals(object a, object b)
{
    if (a == null)
    {
        if (b == null) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    else if (b == null) return false;

    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)) return true;

    var comparable = a as IComparable;
    if (comparable != null)
    {
        return comparable.CompareTo(b) == 0;
    }

    var aType = a.GetType();
    var bType = b.GetType();
    if (aType != bType) return false;

    var aEnumerable = a as IEnumerable;
    if (aEnumerable != null)
    {
        var bEnumerable = (IEnumerable)b;
        var aEnumerator = aEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
        var bEnumerator = bEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
        while (true)
        {
            var amoved = aEnumerator.MoveNext();
            var bmoved = bEnumerator.MoveNext();
            if (amoved != bmoved) return false;
            if (amoved == false && bmoved == false) return true;
            if (DeepEquals(aEnumerator.Current, bEnumerator.Current) == false) return false;
        }
    }

    var props = aType.GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if (DeepEquals(prop.GetValue(a), prop.GetValue(b)) == false) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that this method is not generic. Implementing a generic method is more difficult because you don't know at runtime the type of properties nor the type of the items of collections.